# Song lyric reads 愛 as "ito"

Tags: readings

I was listening to the Song "Miracle Maker" by Spirit of Adventure (better known as the opening song to Digimon World 3 in the Japanese version). The youtube video I was listening it to on had subtitles in both English and Japanese, with both the official lyrics and an unofficial translation. It translated these particular two lines of the song like this:

> 繋がれてゆく魂たちよ
>
> The spirits joining together
>
> 愛しさから離れずに強く
>
> Because of love, they won't separate and be strong

Apart from being an oddly stilted translation, looking into it more I found something especially interesting. In the song, the kanji 愛 is read as "ito" (いと), which I have never heard as a possible reading of 愛.

Is there an explanation for this unusual reading?

Comment: Look up 愛しい in a dictionary, it’s a normal word

Comment: Where did you look? I feel like any ordinary kanji dictionary will include this reading in an entry for 愛.

Answer (score 1):

Not an unusual reading. In all of the online kanji dictionaries I know of, いと（しい） is listed: [jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%84%9B%20%23kanji), [goo dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/kanji/%E6%84%9B/#kanji_kanken-200) and [kanji jiten](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanji/440.html) are some of the examples.

Please note that the hiragana in parenthesis is the okurigana, and this kanji **only** reads いと if it precedes しい or any of its alternative forms: 愛しい, 愛しく, 愛しかった etc.

**Edit:** 愛しい acts as an "～い adjective".

Comment: Some dictionary lists 愛おしい instead of 愛しい, but yeah same thing

Comment: To elaborate: the lyrics use 愛しさ, which is something like an abstract noun form. 愛しい "beloved" -> 愛しさ "belovedness".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've added a line to explain it's an adjective, thanks.